# Best Method For Excel VBA to Get Commands From Central Server

Tags: vba, excel

I'm sure something like this has been asked before but I guess I'm not searching the right keywords because I couldn't find a good answer.

I have created an Excel Add-In used by my entire team. I keep the most recent version on the Network drive and whenever someone re-opens Excel, the add-in checks if there is a new version and updates itself automatically.

What I'd like to do is be able to send commands to the add-ins individually to execute. For instance, if I have an important update to push, rather than waiting for each user to re-open Excel, I'd like to be able to save the command on the Network drive in a text file (i.e. "USER: ALL; COMMAND: UPDATE") and each user's add-in would automatically pick-up that command and process it within a reasonable time frame.

**My question is** what's the best method for accomplishing this? I can think of two solutions off the top of my head, neither of which I like.

*Potential Solution #1* - In 'Worksheet_Calculate' or some similar place, have it check for new commands and process any it finds. However that seems like overkill and would potentially be checking far too often.

*Potential Solution #2* - Use an infinite chain of Application.OnTime calls so that every X seconds/minutes it's checking for new central commands and will process any it finds. However I find Application.OnTime to be funky and unreliable.

Any ideas? I feel like doing something with a Class is the way to go but I don't have much experience with those.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I ended up going with Potential Solution #1.

**Code in ThisWorkbook**

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)

    If mdtLastCheck = 0 Or DateDiff("s", mdtLastCheck, Now) > miCHECK_FREQUENCY_SECONDS Then
        mdtLastCheck = Now

        CheckForCommandsAndRun

    End If

End Sub
```

**Code in MCentralCommands**
*Note the only reference in this module to other modules is to a couple of global variables like gsAPP_MASTER_PATH. This code uses the MErrorHandler system from this book: [Professional Excel Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321508793).*

```
Option Explicit

' Description:  This module contains
'
Private Const msModule As String = "MCentralCommands"

Private Const msCOMMANDS_FOLDER As String = "Commands\"
Private Const msCOMMAND_NAME_FORUSER As String = "CMD_USERNAME_*"
Private Const msCOMMAND_NAME_FORALL As String = "CMD_ALL_*"

Public Const miCHECK_FREQUENCY_SECONDS = 10
Public mdtLastCheck As Date


Sub CheckForCommandsAndRun()

' *********************************************
' Entry-Point Procedure Code Start
' *********************************************
    Const sSource As String = "CheckForCommandsAndRun"
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
' *********************************************
' *********************************************

    Dim sCommands() As String
    If Not bGetNewCommands(sCommands) Then Err.Raise glHANDLED_ERROR
    If Not bProcessAllCommands(sCommands) Then Err.Raise glHANDLED_ERROR

' *********************************************
' Entry-Point Procedure Code Exits
' *********************************************
ErrorExit:
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    If bCentralErrorHandler(msModule, sSource, , True) Then
        Stop
        Resume
    Else
        Resume ErrorExit
    End If

End Sub
Private Function bGetNewCommands(sCommands() As String) As Boolean

' *********************************************
' **** Function Code Start
' *********************************************
    Dim bReturn As Boolean
    Const sSource As String = "bGetNewCommands()"

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    bReturn = True
' *********************************************
' *********************************************

    Dim sCommandPath As String, sUser As String
    sCommandPath = gsAPP_MASTER_PATH & msCOMMANDS_FOLDER
    sUser = UCase(Application.UserName)

    Dim iCommandCount As Integer

    Dim vFile As Variant
    vFile = Dir(sCommandPath)
    While (vFile <> "")
        If vFile Like msCOMMAND_NAME_FORALL Or _
           vFile Like Replace(msCOMMAND_NAME_FORUSER, "USERNAME", sUser) Then _

            ReDim Preserve sCommands(0 To iCommandCount)
            sCommands(iCommandCount) = vFile
            iCommandCount = iCommandCount + 1

        End If

        vFile = Dir
    Wend

' *********************************************
' Function Code Exits
' *********************************************
ErrorExit:
    bGetNewCommands = bReturn
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    bReturn = False
    If bCentralErrorHandler(msModule, sSource) Then
        Stop
        Resume
    Else
        Resume ErrorExit
    End If


End Function
Private Function bProcessAllCommands(sCommands() As String) As Boolean

' *********************************************
' **** Function Code Start
' *********************************************
    Dim bReturn As Boolean
    Const sSource As String = "bProcessAllCommands()"

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    bReturn = True
' *********************************************
' *********************************************

    Dim sCommandPath As String, sUser As String
    sCommandPath = gsAPP_MASTER_PATH & msCOMMANDS_FOLDER
    sUser = UCase(Application.UserName)

    Dim iCmd As Integer
    For iCmd = LBound(sCommands) To UBound(sCommands)
        If Not bProcessCommand(sCommands(iCmd)) Then Err.Raise glHANDLED_ERROR
    Next

' *********************************************
' Function Code Exits
' *********************************************
ErrorExit:
    bProcessAllCommands = bReturn
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    bReturn = False
    If bCentralErrorHandler(msModule, sSource) Then
        Stop
        Resume
    Else
        Resume ErrorExit
    End If


End Function
Private Function bProcessCommand(sCommand As String, Optional bDeleteIfUserCmd As Boolean = True) As Boolean

' *********************************************
' **** Function Code Start
' *********************************************
    Dim bReturn As Boolean
    Const sSource As String = "bProcessCommand()"

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    bReturn = True
' *********************************************
' *********************************************

    Dim sCommandPath As String, sUser As String
    sCommandPath = gsAPP_MASTER_PATH & msCOMMANDS_FOLDER
    sUser = UCase(Application.UserName)

    Dim bHaveIRun As Boolean, bCommandSuccessful As Boolean
    If Not bHaveIRunCommand(sCommand, bHaveIRun) Then Err.Raise glHANDLED_ERROR

    If Not bHaveIRun Then

        If Not bRunCommand(sCommand, bCommandSuccessful) Then Err.Raise glHANDLED_ERROR
        If bCommandSuccessful Then
            If Not bMarkCommandAsRan(sCommand) Then Err.Raise glHANDLED_ERROR
            MLog.Log "Ran: " & sCommand
        End If

    End If

' *********************************************
' Function Code Exits
' *********************************************
ErrorExit:
    bProcessCommand = bReturn
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    bReturn = False
    If bCentralErrorHandler(msModule, sSource) Then
        Stop
        Resume
    Else
        Resume ErrorExit
    End If


End Function
Private Function bRunCommand(sCommand As String, bCommandSuccessful As Boolean) As Boolean

' *********************************************
' **** Function Code Start
' *********************************************
    Dim bReturn As Boolean
    Const sSource As String = "bRunCommand()"

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    bReturn = True
' *********************************************
' *********************************************

    Dim sCommandName As String
    sCommandName = Replace(Mid(sCommand, InStrRev(sCommand, "_") + 1), ".txt", "")

    Select Case UCase(sCommandName)
        Case "MSGBOX":
            Dim sMsgBoxText As String
            If Not bGetParameterFromCommand(sCommand, "Msg", sMsgBoxText) Then Err.Raise glHANDLED_ERROR
            MsgBox sMsgBoxText
            bCommandSuccessful = True

        Case "UPDATE":
            CheckForUpdates False
            bCommandSuccessful = True

        Case "OLFLDRS":
            UpdateSavedOutlookFolderList
            bCommandSuccessful = True

    End Select



' *********************************************
' Function Code Exits
' *********************************************
ErrorExit:
    bRunCommand = bReturn
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    bReturn = False
    If bCentralErrorHandler(msModule, sSource) Then
        Stop
        Resume
    Else
        Resume ErrorExit
    End If


End Function
Private Function bGetParameterFromCommand(sCommand As String, sParameterName As String, sParameterReturn As String) As Boolean

' *********************************************
' **** Function Code Start
' *********************************************
    Dim bReturn As Boolean
    Const sSource As String = "bGetParameterFromCommand()"

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    bReturn = True
' *********************************************
' *********************************************

    Dim sCommandPath As String, sUser As String
    sCommandPath = gsAPP_MASTER_PATH & msCOMMANDS_FOLDER
    sUser = UCase(Application.UserName)

    Dim sFilePath As String, sParameterText() As String, sTextLine As String
    Dim iLineCount As Integer
    sFilePath = sCommandPath & sCommand

    Dim bBegin As Boolean

    Open sFilePath For Input As #1
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, sTextLine

        If bBegin Then If Left(sTextLine, 1) = ":" Then bBegin = False
        If sTextLine Like "*:Parameters:*" Then
            bBegin = True
        End If

        If bBegin Then
            ReDim Preserve sParameterText(0 To iLineCount)
            sParameterText(iLineCount) = sTextLine
            iLineCount = iLineCount + 1
        End If
    Loop
    Close #1

    Dim iParameterCounter As Integer
    For iParameterCounter = LBound(sParameterText) To UBound(sParameterText)
        If sParameterText(iParameterCounter) Like sParameterName & ": *" Then _
            sParameterReturn = Mid(sParameterText(iParameterCounter), InStr(1, sParameterText(iParameterCounter), " ") + 1)
    Next


' *********************************************
' Function Code Exits
' *********************************************
ErrorExit:
    bGetParameterFromCommand = bReturn
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    bReturn = False
    If bCentralErrorHandler(msModule, sSource) Then
        Stop
        Resume
    Else
        Resume ErrorExit
    End If


End Function
Private Function bHaveIRunCommand(sCommand As String, bHaveIRun As Boolean) As Boolean

' *********************************************
' **** Function Code Start
' *********************************************
    Dim bReturn As Boolean
    Const sSource As String = "bHaveIRunCommand()"

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    bReturn = True
' *********************************************
' *********************************************

    Dim sCommandPath As String, sUser As String
    sCommandPath = gsAPP_MASTER_PATH & msCOMMANDS_FOLDER
    sUser = UCase(Application.UserName)

    Dim sFile As String, sText As String, sTextLine As String
    sFile = sCommandPath & sCommand

    Dim bBegin As Boolean

    Open sFile For Input As #1
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, sTextLine

        If bBegin Then If Left(sTextLine, 1) = ":" Then bBegin = False
        If sTextLine Like "*:Run By Users:*" Then bBegin = True

        If bBegin Then
            sText = sText & sTextLine
        End If
    Loop
    Close #1

    bHaveIRun = sText Like "*" & sUser & "*"

' *********************************************
' Function Code Exits
' *********************************************
ErrorExit:
    bHaveIRunCommand = bReturn
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    bReturn = False
    If bCentralErrorHandler(msModule, sSource) Then
        Stop
        Resume
    Else
        Resume ErrorExit
    End If


End Function
Private Function bMarkCommandAsRan(sCommand As String) As Boolean

' *********************************************
' **** Function Code Start
' *********************************************
    Dim bReturn As Boolean
    Const sSource As String = "bMarkCommandAsRan()"

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    bReturn = True
' *********************************************
' *********************************************

    Dim sCommandPath As String, sUser As String
    sCommandPath = gsAPP_MASTER_PATH & msCOMMANDS_FOLDER
    sUser = UCase(Application.UserName)

    Dim sFilePath As String, sRanText As String, sTextLine As String, bHaveIRun As Boolean
    Dim sFullText() As String, iLineCount As Integer, iRunBy As Integer
    sFilePath = sCommandPath & sCommand

    Dim bBegin As Boolean

    Open sFilePath For Input As #1
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, sTextLine

        ReDim Preserve sFullText(0 To iLineCount)
        sFullText(iLineCount) = sTextLine
        iLineCount = iLineCount + 1

        If bBegin Then If Left(sTextLine, 1) = ":" Then bBegin = False
        If sTextLine Like "*:Run By Users:*" Then
            bBegin = True
            iRunBy = iLineCount - 1
        End If

        If bBegin Then
            sRanText = sRanText & sTextLine
        End If
    Loop
    Close #1

    bHaveIRun = sRanText Like "*" & sUser & "*"

    If Not bHaveIRun Then
        Dim iCounter As Integer

        Open sFilePath For Output As #1
        For iLineCount = LBound(sFullText) To UBound(sFullText)
            Print #1, sFullText(iLineCount)
            If iLineCount = iRunBy Then _
                Print #1, sUser
        Next
        Close #1
    End If


' *********************************************
' Function Code Exits
' *********************************************
ErrorExit:
    bMarkCommandAsRan = bReturn
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    bReturn = False
    If bCentralErrorHandler(msModule, sSource) Then
        Stop
        Resume
    Else
        Resume ErrorExit
    End If


End Function
```